# How to keep files without overwriting in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

We are using azure for our application. Everytime I deploy a new version of the application through Visual Studio it removes all files from azure storage and puts a fresh version from my local files. What I want to do is to leave some files on the server un-touched, that is when I deploy new version these special files won't get overwritten with my local version. Is it possible? I have some Lucene Indexes that I don't want to overwrite and I dont want to move it to blob storage either.

Answer (score 0):

Set LocalStorage::cleanOnRecycle attribute of the service definition to false:

[Worker role service definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557552#LocalStorage)

Comment: Where do I set it? How will it know which files to overwrite and which ones leave un-touched?

Comment: It won't, but the setting will stop files from being recycled.  You will then need to build the logic into your role, either via the OnStartup method or a startup task: [link] (http://blog.smarx.com/posts/introduction-to-windows-azure-startup-tasks)